# Dual coil supply for safety relay

Tags: power-supply, relay

I need to make an ancillary safety circuit (e-stop) for a machine using safety relay (SR4 D and M if you're curious, they have trick contacts). The big issue is that the machine has to be run with either 12V or 24V.

The SR4 have an 800mW coil and are readily available at 12V (the 5V are a little more difficult to find) and the circuit has 3 relays (the standard dual channel estop circuitry can be found in application notes if you are interested). With the machine turned off only one relay is engaged, in the run position the other two are; in between there are caps to handle the coil switchover.

So, in short, the load is always 70-140mA, outside of that it could happily pop a fuse because something is faulty. The problem is the supply range.
The relay has a must-hold rating of 9V so some dropout is tolerable, there could be some supply dips but the caps on the coil should handle these. On the high side nominal is 24-28 and brief surges up to 32 (these are already eaten up by varistors).

First idea: a big resistor/12V zener regulator. Too bad that to cover the whole range something huge would be needed (more than 10W by estimate)

Second idea: some regulator like a TO220 LM7812. Still more than 2W to dissipate but the TO220 is more amenable to that. It would eat in my brownout budget (about 2-2.5V) but should work.

Third idea: some switching regulator, a 2:1 range would be quite easy but many regulators have issues in undervolt (often they simply shut down). I could set the feedback to have something like 9.5V to keep in the duty cycle limit or look for some part with bypass of wide duty range.

Any better idea? Comments on the plan?

Comment: "Trick contacts" don't sound like something I would like in a safety system. What do you mean by "trick"? I think your question is basically, "How best should I power a 12 V safety relay with a 9 V drop-out voltage when the input supply voltage is either 12 or 24 V but can dip to XX V? The required current is 140 mA max."

Comment: It's not uncommon for safety circuits to be on DC to DC isolating power supplies, this is one reason why they can help buffer supply issues.

Comment: The 'trick' is indeed a safety feature… when one NO contact welds the NC can't reclose and vice-versa; there's a lot of standard circuitry to detect and handle redundantly this *using only relays*. My issue was powering them from a wide supply. At the end I'm probably doing a cheap switcher since they alway cost a lot anyway.